# How to get list installed Linux rpms with Python?

Tags: python, rpm

I use `subprocess.getoutput("rpm -qa").split("\n")`,it's not very well. `rpmfile` module can only read .rpm files

Can you help me find one module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to check if a package is installed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27833644/608639), [Determine if package installed with Yum Python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8439074/608639), [Check if one package is installed in my system with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24940797/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Fedora, there is a module called `rpm` from the package `rpm-python` that will allow you to query the rpm database:

```
import rpm

ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch()
for h in mi:
    print "%s-%s-%s" % (h['name'], h['version'], h['release'])
```

That is a simple piece of code from the documentation. See [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s03s02.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe code below is useful for someone.

```
import os
f = os.popen('rpm -qa')
arq = f.readlines()
#print("First file=" + arq[0].strip())
for x in arq:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified code similar to what is posted by Marcus Poli. This was tested using Python 2.7 and 3.6 on CentOS 7.4. My original question was [How do I check if an rpm package is installed using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375889/how-do-i-check-if-an-rpm-package-is-installed-using-python?noredirect=1#comment104945661_59375889)

```
import os
rpm = 'binutils'
f = os.popen('rpm -qa')
arq = f.readlines()
for r in arq:
   if rpm in r:
      print("{} is installed".format(r.rstrip()))
```

Output:

```
binutils-devel-2.27-34.base.el7.x86_64 is installed
binutils-2.27-34.base.el7.x86_64 is installed
```