# How do I check if an rpm package is installed using Python?

Tags: python, linux, installation, rpm

I am writing a Python 2.7 app that relies on several rpm packages to be installed. There is a planned port to Python 3 in the near future. Is there a simple function call to check if an rpm is installed that works in both versions of Python?

e.g.

```
rpm = "binutils"
if package_installed(rpm):
    print("{} is installed".format(rpm))
```

Comment: I imagine you're on a *RH* based *OS*. *YUM* (*RPM* wrapper) is written in *Python*.

Comment: I am on CentOS 7.4. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to check if a package is installed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27833644/608639), [Determine if package installed with Yum Python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8439074/608639), [Check if one package is installed in my system with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24940797/608639), [How to get list installed Linux rpms with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34360353/608639) and friends.

Comment: That is sort of a duplicate; more like a similar topic. Some of the answers previously posted is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

rpm = 'binutils'

f = os.popen('rpm -qa')
arq = f.readlines()
if rpm in arq:
    print("{} is installed".format(rpm))
```

Comment: I had to tweak this to get it to work using Python 2.7 and 3.6. Posted under [How to get list installed Linux rpms with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360353/how-to-get-list-installed-linux-rpms-with-python)